# ruby 1.9.3 why does JSON.generate(h) throw UndefinedConversionError error but h.to_json does not

Tags: ruby, json

For one particular set of data, our usual code to convert a hash to JSON is throwing an error:

```
the_json = JSON.generate(h)
=> Encoding::UndefinedConversionError: "\xC3" from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8
```

While trying to find WHICH character was causing the problem we noticed that using to_json does not throw an error

```
h.to_json
=> (very long string that looks correct)
```

Does anyone have any ideas on

(a) how to find the offending character so we can track down how it is occuring

(b) why JSON.generate is more fragile than to_json?

(c) and MOST importantly: how to invoke JSON.generate in such a way as to force_encoding (like many other ruby methods allow) so that a when the hash contains a name like "Sjöholm" it gets handled without throwing an exception.

Comment: Hmm, looks like `JSON.generate` is using a different form of UTF validation than `to_json`...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like the `to_json` method doesn't do UTF-8 validation whereas `JSON.generate` does:

```
"\xC3" =~ /./         # => ArgumentError: invalid byte sequence in UTF-8
JSON.generate("\xC3") # => ArgumentError: invalid byte sequence in UTF-8
"\xC3".to_json        # => "\"\xC3\"" XXX: not valid UTF-8
```

In my experience, attempting to regex match a string is a simple and reliable way to ensure proper UTF-8  encoding (hence the first line of the examples above).